# How can I limit the number of characters to select in a PostgreSQL substring?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to pull off the first part of an email before the `@` symbol.

This works:

```
SELECT substring(email, '(\S+)(@{1})')
```

However I'd like to also only pull off the first 15 (or less) characters.

How can I do this?

```
SELECT substring(email, '(\S+)(@{1})', 15)
```

doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: `LEFT(substring(email,'(\S+)(@{1})'), 15)`?

Comment: Can you please provide an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
select left(substring(email, '^[^@]*'), 15)
```

Or, if you want one regular expression:

```
select substring(email, '^[^@]{1,15}')
```